# How to modify or remove few characters from URL in discord.js

Tags: node.js, url, discord, discord.js

I've a small issue and tried to work around, but its not working. I'm using discord.js to send messages to channels. Its working fine, except the URL part, some urls have trailing [1], for ex. http....xyz.com/something/[1] like this. I tried below method of replace too, which is working in fiddle but not when implementing in my code.

**Replace method**

```
let string = 'https://www.tradingview.com/x/0Mf3zuVw/[1]'; // just an example
let result = string.replace('[1]', '');
console.log(result);
```

**My code here i think some changes has to be done in ProxyUrl**

```
const channel = client.channels.get(message.channel.id)
let content = `**${message.channel.parent.name}**\n${channel.name}\n${message.content}`  
message.attachments.forEach(attachment => {
content += `\n ${attachment.ProxyUrl} `  
})
```

So it seems something has to be done around ProxyUrl, like string replace etc.
Let me know what changes shall i do.
Thanks again

Comment: Can't you just apply above replacment on the `attachment.ProxyUrl`?

Comment: i tried by first creating 
let string =`\n ${attachment.ProxyUrl} `
content += string.replace('[1]', '');
But result came same with trailing [1]

Comment: You can use replace directly on the `ProxyUrl` - note that this will remove only the first `[1]` in the `ProxyUrl`. Are there more? If yes, we need to change it a bit.

Comment: i tried 
content += `\n ${attachment.ProxyUrl.replace('[1]', '')} `
Still its not replacing/removing [1] making url invalid

Comment: Could it be that `message.content` already contains those [1]? If so you need to do `content = content.replace(/\[1\]/g, '');` at the very end.

Comment: you nailed it man, its solved now, plz update ur answer below so i accept it.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the replacement logic you posted is correct, you can apply it as follows to each attachment's `ProxyUrl`:

```
message.attachments.forEach(attachment => {
    content += `\n ${attachment.ProxyUrl.replace('[1]', '')}`; 
})
```

In case multiple `[1]` are contained in the url, you can remove all of them using this:

```
message.attachments.forEach(attachment => {
    content += `\n ${attachment.ProxyUrl.replace(/\[1\]/g, '')}`; 
})
```

In case that `message.content` already contains `[1]`, you need to do

`content = content.replace(/\[1\]/g, '');`

at the very end.

Comment: one more thing, for multiple replace what to be done.
Like in every message i get this
<@&577534787502211073>
how to remove same

Comment: You can build a regex for this as well, maybe check a tutorial like this here: https://medium.com/factory-mind/regex-tutorial-a-simple-cheatsheet-by-examples-649dc1c3f285 if you haven't worked wit them before, I think you will be able to figure it out :)